# Why am I not getting a popupmenu to appear in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm working through an Eclipse plugins book. I had an earlier question of [Simple SWT/JFace exercise fails to find handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33190307/simple-swt-jface-exercise-fails-to-find-handler?noredirect=1#comment54187129_33190307).

I'm now working on a popupmenu exercise.  I have a tree view and a table view, and I'm attempting to render the same popup menu on both views (this is all from the instructions in the book).

In the `createPartControl` method of each view, I've added code like the following:

```
 MenuManager manager = new MenuManager("#PopupMenu");
 Menu menu = manager.createContextMenu(viewer.getControl());
 viewer.getControl().setMenu(menu);
 getSite().registerContextMenu(manager, viewer);
```

where the "viewer" is either a `TableViewer` or a `TreeViewer`.

I added the following `menuContribution`:

```xml
 <menuContribution allPopups="false" locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any">
     <command commandId="com.packtpub.e4.clock.ui.command.showTheTime"
           label="Show the Time" style="push">
        <visibleWhen checkEnabled="false">
           <with variable="selection">
              <iterate ifEmpty="false">
                 <adapt type="java.util.TimeZone">
                 </adapt>
              </iterate>
           </with>
        </visibleWhen>
     </command>
 </menuContribution>
```

along with this command:

```xml
 <command description="Shows the Time"
        id="com.packtpub.e4.clock.ui.command.showTheTime"
        name="Show the Time">
 </command>
```

and this handler:

```xml
 <handler class="com.packtpub.e4.clock.ui.handlers.ShowTheTime"
        commandId="com.packtpub.e4.clock.ui.command.showTheTime">
 </handler>
```

The following is the handler class:

```
public class ShowTheTime extends AbstractHandler {
 public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) {
    ISelection sel = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event).getSelectionService().getSelection();
    if (sel instanceof IStructuredSelection && !sel.isEmpty()) {
        Object value = ((IStructuredSelection)sel).getFirstElement();
        if (value instanceof TimeZone) {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
            sdf.setTimeZone((TimeZone) value);
            MessageDialog.openInformation(null, "The time is", sdf.format(new Date()));
        } 
    }
    return null;
 }
}
```

When I run the instance and right-click on the tree or table, I get ... nothing. Nothing happens.

Is it possible that the "iterate" with "adapt" isn't finding a selection matching that type (`java.util.TimeZone`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add a menu item to the context menu telling Eclipse where to put the additional menu items:

```
manager.add(new Separator(IWorkbenchActionConstants.MB_ADDITIONS));
```

The `menuContribution` will only add to a menu which has the `MB_ADDITIONS` id for one of its entries (unless you specify `allPopus="true"` or specify a specific position).

You must also tell the view site that your table/tree is the selection provider for the part:

```
getSite().setSelectionProvider(viewer);
```

The selection service only looks at the selection provider for a view / editor site when determining what is selected.

The objects you have in your table/tree content provider must implement `java.util.TimeZone` or use the adapter manager to adapt to that class.

Comment: When I tried to add that first line, it pointed out that there is no "add" method on Menu.

Comment: That worked.  Could you elaborate on these points a little more (first two, mostly)?